# Cómo paginar con render() ajax y laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Hola estoy intentando paginar una tabla Mysql, estoy utilizando ajax pero cuando utilizo ajax no puedo obtener la respuesta del controlador mediante blade, sólo me llega la respuesta a Javascript.
Deseo obtener en blade lo que la petición ajax me devuelve.

Mi vista :

```
<table class="mi_tabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
<tr>
@if(isset($personas))   
@foreach($personas as $persona)
<td>{{$persona->nombre}}</td>
<td>{{$persona->apellido}}</td>
<td>{{$persona->cedula}}</td>
@endforeach
@endif
</tr>

</table>
```

Mi Modelo:

```
class Personas extends Model
{
    protected $table='clientes';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    public $timestamps=false;
}
```

Mi controlador :

```
class Busqueda extends Controller
{

    public function proceso(Request $request)
    {
        $personas = Personas::all();
        return response()->with('personas',$personas);
    }
}
```

Mi Peticion Ajax .

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$('.enviar').click(function(event) {
  $('.mi_tabla').html("<thead><tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Cedula</th><th>Opciones</th></tr></thead>");
  $.post('ajax', {}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  alert(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar una paginación mediante ajax hay muchos escenarios posibles, te dejo una forma en la que lo puedes hacer:

1.Adjuntar un evento para detectar el clic en tus botones de paginación, evitar que recargue la página y obtener la url a donde te quiere dirigir (para obtener el número de página al que quieres acceder), entonces, usando jQuery podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    recargarTabla(url);     
});
```

Presta atención al `$(document).on("click",...)` ya que tienes que escuchar a ese evento en todo el documento para cuando estés creando la paginación dinámica. Después creas la función `recargarTabla` y haces lo siguiente:

```
function recargarTabla(url){
      $.get(url, function(data, status){
         $('.lista-registros').html(data.registros);
      });
   }
```

En esta parte harás una petición get para obtener los resultados que deseas, le mandas como parámetro la URL a la que quieres acceder de la paginación, y como segundo parámetro es la función que se ejecutará una vez terminado el proceso, en esta función solo pegaremos el html que te devuelva, tendrás que tener listo un elemento `<div>` con la clase especificada `<div class="lista-registros"></div>`, el cual contendrá la lista de tus registros.

2.Del lado de tu servidor, en el método que se encargue de hacer la consulta de tu listado (en tu caso me parece que se llama `proceso`) pondrás lo siguiente:

```
//Antes de ejecutar esto tendrías que estar haciendo tu consulta en donde obtienes tus registros, en este ejemplo los contiene una variable llamada "registros"
if($request->ajax()){
   return [
        'registros' => view('layouts.partials.listados.registros')->with(compact('registros'))->render(),
        'next_page' => $registros->nextPageUrl()
    ];
}
```

En esta parte del código verificas que la petición sea ajax y de ser así, regresas la vista ya "rendereada" con los registros correspondientes. La vista que usarás sugiero que solo contenga la parte del listado de tus registros, y dentro de esta plantilla blade debe de contener la parte de la paginación: `{{ $registros->links() }}` en alguna sección de esa plantilla (eres igualmente libre de escribir cualquier ruta en la que se encuentre ubicada). El segundo parámetro `next_page` es por si te es de utilidad saber cual página le sigue a la actual que estás consultando pero lo puedes omitir.

De esa forma estarías obteniendo tu paginación sin ningún problema, ya que con esta línea de código de javascript `$('.lista-registros').html(data.registros);` estarías pegando el html que estés devolviendo.

Para realizar lo mismo pero con filtros solo tendrías que ir pasando los parámetros y añadirlos en la paginación si existen como lo siguiente: `{{ $registros->appends(['estado' => ($estado ? $estado : '')])->links() }}`